# Singletion pattern for C++ logger

Tags: c++

I need to design a logger class which will be used by all other classed to log the messages. Currently I am creating the poiner of logger in each of my classes and calling the method of logger thorugh the logger pointer to log the messages. I want to design it in singleton pattern way and it has to be thread safe. Can anyone suggest a good approach.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern?rq=1 Have you checked this?

Comment: It is unlikely you need a singleton, so concentrate on a thread safe logger that is not a singleton. This simplifies the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about singleton, simply make everything in the class `static`.  You will likely want to provide macros to easily access the log method, for example:

```
#define logdbg(fmt, ...) Log::log(__FUNCTION__, Log::LEVEL_DEBUG, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Which, when implemented as a singleton would need to be:

```
#define logdbg(fmt, ...) Log::instance().log(__FUNCTION__, Log::LEVEL_DEBUG, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Which makes very little difference.

Comment: I think this is ignoring the thread safety issue, which could be the main point (although it is difficult to know for sure what OPs requirements are.)

Comment: @juanchopanza How does the singleton pattern help with thread safety?

Comment: I never said it did. Obviously it doesn't. But there is nothing in your solution that addresses thread safety, and that seems to be one of OP's concerns.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, I see your point.